# Multiple Instances of Postgresql Conflicting

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have ubuntu linux server. I had postgresql 9.3 installed on it, but to install an extension I mistakenly upgraded the postgresql server to 9.4. Still everything was running fine, but after the server restart I am not been able to connect to postgresql 9.3, 
I get the error could not connect to server: No such file or directory , Is the server running locally and accepting connections on unix domain socket "var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

If I look at var/run/postgresql, I don't see .s.PGSQL.5432 but a .s.PGSQLl.5433.
I need to connect to postgresql on port 5432 as all my databases are on it.
Could someone please tell, how can I access postgresql server on port 5432 without loosing any data.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu allows for  several versions of PostgreSQL to be run simultaneously. See from process list (`ps aux`) that the 9.3 @ 5432 is indeed running; if not, start it with `sudo service postgresql start 9.3`.

Comment: After running `ps aux` , I see many postgresql services, but how I would know which version of postgresql is running. After `running sudo service postgresql restart`, it asks for postgres password. I have also lost the password for postgres

Comment: just try starting postgresql 9.3 with the command I gave, it is safe.

Comment: @Antii Haapala, can you just check my updated comment

Comment: @SahilAgarwal No, it asks for *your* password, or maybe you should be executing this command with your account.

Comment: It asks for postgres password, which I have lost. I am having the root access

Comment: then execute the `sudo service postgresql restart 9.3` with your user account, not postgresql account. it would ask for your password on ubuntu.

Comment: I get invalid mode in start.conf. No Postgresql clusters exist